# Why does an $n$th degree polynomial have at most $n-1$ turning points?

Tags: functions, polynomials

How can one explain that polynomial of degree $n$ can have up to $n-1$ turning points and $n$ intersections with the $x$-axis?

If it is easier to explain, why can't a cubic function have three or more turning points?

Usually, these two phenomenons are just given, but I couldn't find an explanation for such polynomial function behavior.

Comment: So the title should be "at most" $n-1$ turning points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of turning points is the number of solutions to the equation $${dy\over dx}=0$$ and the derivative of a polynomial has one less power of $x$ than the polynomial itself. The number of intersections with the x axis is the number of roots of the polynomial. The statement that a polynomial of order $n$ has $n$ roots is called the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofAlgebra.html).

Comment: I would say solutions $x_0\in\mathbb R$ to the equation $\frac{dy}{dx}\small{(x_0)} = 0$. Also the fact that a polynomial can have at most $n$ roots is just basic algebra.

Comment: @GPerez What is the point of your comment?

Comment: Just correcting bits of your answer, so OP gets the right idea.

Comment: To be specific, my first remark is to avoid confusion with differential equations, and the second is to say two things: you don't need to go as far as the fundamental theorem of algebra, and in fact it doesn't depend on being in $\mathbb C$ or even $\mathbb Q$, for that matter.

Comment: @GPerez You didn't "correct" anything by saying that, you're confusing the issue. OP asked for the reason why.

Comment: Yes, the question was why, and @SuzuHirose gave me a clue. I know the theory, but I want to understand in a nutshell why such a phenomenon is happening. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: @chao I understand this, and the "nutshell" is not given by the fundamental theorem of algebra, it's given by the [Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem). Disregard the part about the derivatives if you like, but this I have to insist on. I also want to say that it's quite natural to get comments that offer specification or an alternate point of view on an answer, and it's not meant to offend anyone, it's just for the math. See the other answer for example.

Comment: @GPerez Is there any good description of this theorem that uses less math proofs and gives more description through text/images? According to the wiki page, I don't see how this theorem effects on turning points/zeros.

Comment: @chao Well, it affects the number of roots of a polynomial, which in turn has consequences for turning points, since these have to coincide with roots of a certain polynomial (namely, the derivative of polynomial you wish to study). How the Remainder theorem affects roots: if $r$ is a root, $(x-r)$ divides the polynomial, because the remainder (thanks to the theorem) is $P(r)=0$, because $r$ is a root. So you can't have more roots than the degree, because the $P$ would have more factors of degree $1$ than its own degree, which clearly cannot be.

Answer (score 5):

A degree $n$ polynomial has at most $n$ roots (intersections with the $x$ axis). A "turning point" is a place where the derivative of the polynomial is zero (though not every place the derivative vanishes is a turning point), and since the derivative of a degree $n$ polynomial is a degree $n-1$ polynomial, there are at most $n-1$ turning points.

Comment: It'd be more accurate/clear to say "The derivative of a polynomial is $0$ at a turning point" - as it's written now, it looks like "derivative is 0" and "turning point" are equivalent, rather than just the latter implying the former.

Comment: You're right, of course.